# How to contact a user who wrote a review to my app?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I have published an app in the App Store. Now one of the customers/buyer wrote a review regarding a technical issue.

How can I contact that person? In the review I can only see the author's pseudonym.

Answer (score 3):

Since a few days, you now have the ability to answer to reviews, right from iTunes Connect.

Go to **My Apps > YourApp > Activity > Reviews** and you will be able to click on **Answer** for each review.

Your answers will be available directly from the App Store for people running on iOS 10.3, and <del>I think</del> the reviewer also receive a mail <del>or notification</del> that you answered.

**It a huge step from Apple to finally offer this !**

[image: Apple doc]

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. If you wish to help users you could list an email adress in your app and/or let them immediately email to it. Apple does not allow you to reply to user reviews in the app store.